# How to use Data.Text.Lazy.IO to parse JSON files with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation, aeson

I want to parse all json files in a given directory into a data type *Result*.

So i have a decode function

```
decodeResult :: Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString -> Maybe Result
```

I began with *Data.Text.Lazy.IO* to load file into Lazy ByteString,

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as T

getFileContent :: FilePath -> IO B.ByteString
getFileContent path = T.encodeUtf8 `fmap` T.readFile path
```

It compiled, but I ran into Too many files opened problem, so I thought maybe I should use [*withFile*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile).

```
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as T

getFileContent :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe Result)
getFileContent path = withFile path ReadMode $ \hnd -> do
   content <- T.hGetContents hnd
   return $ (decodeAnalytic . T.encodeUtf8) content

loadAllResults :: FilePath -> IO [Result]
loadAllResults path = do
   paths <- listDirectory path
   results <- sequence $ fmap getFileContent (fmap (path ++ ) $ filter (endswith ".json") paths)
   return $ catMaybes results
```

In this version, the lazy io seems never got evaluated, it always return empty list. But If i print content inside *getFileContent* function, then everything seems work correctly.

```
getFileContent :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe Result)
getFileContent path = withFile path ReadMode $ \hnd -> do
   content <- T.hGetContents hnd
   print content
   return $ (decodeAnalytic . T.encodeUtf8) content
```

So I am not sure what am I missing, should I use conduit for this type of things?

Comment: The simple answer is yes, use conduit or the like. The more complicated answer is, your `loadAllResults` is *incredibly* lazy - simply executing `loadAllResults x` does not actually read any files (or indeed, open them). When you try to evaluate the resulting list, you simultaneously open all the files and try to read them. `withFile` doesn't help you because the laziness comes from `hGetContents` - try switching to non-lazy Text IO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking I *would* recommend using a streaming library for parsing arbitrarily sized data like a JSON file. However, in the specific case of parsing JSON with aeson, the concerns of overrunning memory are not as significant IMO, since the aeson library itself will ultimately represent the entire file in memory as a `Value` type. So given that, you may choose to simply use strict bytestring I/O. I've given an example of using both conduit and strict I/O for parsing a JSON value. (I think the conduit version exists in some libraries already, I'm not sure.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-7.14 --install-ghc runghc
   --package aeson --package conduit-extra
-}
import           Control.Monad.Catch     (MonadThrow, throwM)
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (MonadIO, liftIO)
import           Data.Aeson              (FromJSON, Result (..), eitherDecodeStrict',
                                          fromJSON, json, Value)
import           Data.ByteString         (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString         as B
import           Data.Conduit            (ConduitM, runConduitRes, (.|))
import           Data.Conduit.Attoparsec (sinkParser)
import           Data.Conduit.Binary     (sourceFile)

sinkFromJSON :: (MonadThrow m, FromJSON a) => ConduitM ByteString o m a
sinkFromJSON = do
    value <- sinkParser json
    case fromJSON value of
        Error e -> throwM $ userError e
        Success x -> return x

readJSONFile :: (MonadIO m, FromJSON a) => FilePath -> m a
readJSONFile fp = liftIO $ runConduitRes $ sourceFile fp .| sinkFromJSON

-- Or using strict I/O
readJSONFileStrict :: (MonadIO m, FromJSON a) => FilePath -> m a
readJSONFileStrict fp = liftIO $ do
    bs <- B.readFile fp
    case eitherDecodeStrict' bs of
        Left e -> throwM $ userError e
        Right x -> return x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- readJSONFile "test.json"
    y <- readJSONFileStrict "test.json"
    print (x :: Value)
    print (y :: Value)
```

**EDIT** Forgot to mention: I'd strongly recommend *against* using textual I/O for reading your JSON files. JSON files should be encoded with UTF-8, while the textual I/O functions will use whatever your system settings specify for character encoding. Relying on `Data.ByteString.readFile` and similar is more reliable. I went into more detail [in a recent blog post](http://www.snoyman.com/blog/2016/12/beware-of-readfile).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!